# Postfix working as backend/local MTA

Tags: postfix, load-balancing, email-server

I'm in the process of configuring an email platform and I would like to clear some doubts that I have.

When building this system I have 2 options:

1. Have `PHP` doing the connections to my `SMTP` external server (it's a
   delivery only server). This is how my network is configured at the
   moment and I feel it's very heavy on the server.
2. Have `PHP` connecting to my local `MTA` and having the local `MTA`
   (`Postfix`) connecting through `SMTP` to my external delivery server

I think the option 2 is the preferable one for a couple of reasons:

- Dispatch from the email platform is faster
- `PHP` processes will finish faster
- Delivery itself will be on Postfix (local MTA) responsibility thus creating a new layer on the delivery data flow providing a lot more abstraction on the `PHP` platform
- Delivery rules can be defined specifically on `Postfix`

So, question 1 is if this is the preferable solution or if I should keep option 1?

Bellow is a small representation of what I'm referring in point 2:

```
                                                                  +------------+
                                                                  |            |
                              +---> smtp external backend a ----->|            |
                              |                                   |            |
platform -------> local MTA lb ---> smtp external backend b ----->|  Delivery  |
                              |                                   |            |
                              +---> smtp external backend c ----->|            |
                                                                  |            |
                                                                  +------------+
```

Question 2:

If this is the preferable situation how can I create a load balance `Postfix` solution?

I need to be able to easily add and remove `SMTP` servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First. Two questions in one is bad!

1) As you didn't find negative arguments for option 2 you should choose option 2.

2) You need no Postfix load balancer. Postfix on a recent machine is able to deliver 100 mails per second. With good hard-drives and a bit of queue management even more. I don't know why to extend that? And if you really really really need it then you should have an in-house DNS server with low TTL and use multiple A records for your local MTA (1b). The DNS is then doing round-robin load balancing for you.

Comment: Thank you mailq. Sorry about the 2 questions, I felt they were closely related. I'm going to investigate a bit more on the DNS round-robin as it really appears to be the best solution for what I want.